# Install OS X Lion on a Mac mini

Tags: macos, install

I borrowed a Core 2 Duo Mac mini. I want to back up the HDD and wipe off the OS Leopard that it has so that I can later re-install it back. Then I want to upgrade to OS X Lion. Can this Mac mini run Lion? What steps should I take?
specs here:
mac mini 3.1
Intel core 2 duo 2.26ghz
4gb ram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1GB of RAM is insufficient for OS X 10.7 "Lion."  [You'll need 2GB or more.](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP629):

OS X Lion - Technical Specifications
General requirements

- Mac computer with an Intel Core 2 Duo, Core i3, Core i5, Core i7, or
  Xeon processor
- 2GB of memory
- OS X v10.6.6 or later (v10.6.8 recommended)
- 7GB of available space

Comment: And if you get more RAM for your mini, I would start by installing Lion on to an external drive. You can boot off an external OS quite easily on Mac until you get used to imaging / backing up / restoring.

Comment: updated the specs..i have 4gb ram

Comment: Then both Lion and Mountain Lion will run quite well - personally I'd recommend ML instead.

Comment: is there any article detailing steps to clone the existing snow leopard before i start installing lion and steps to install lion for a usb drive. i've a dmg image

Comment: I'm a fan of [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) for cloning an existing system, but there are other options like SuperDuper that can do this as well.  Remember to test booting from the cloned/backup before making changes to the original system.  Then use Disk Utility to restore the InstalLESD.dmg from inside the Install Lion.app package to your flash drive.